SSRS - how to position chart columns
I have a simple column chart which can only output 3 columns.  As the labels are quite large I have been asked to position the first and third columns at the extremes of the x-axis (mock-up below - ignore the values mismatch):

However, SSRS is automatically positioning the columns too close together:

I have tried changing as many of the Category Axis properties and Series properties as I can, but none seem to have any effect.  The only one coming close is the series' PointWidth property, but this only affects the width of the columns, not the offset positioning of the first and third columns.
Any suggestions?

One workaround could be adding dummy bars with no data like in the example below.
You can change the dummy bar CustomProperties to match your needs.



